# Why in shell script output file get written as single line?

Tags: bash, shell

Input file: ankit.txt with header date and trailer count

```
H2014-12-02
12ASDF23 FGHJ HJKL
123ASD23 FGHJ HJKL
123ASD23 FGHJ HJKL
123ASD23 FGHJ HJKL
T000004
```

I want data without header and trailer.

Command:

```
head -n -1 ankit.txt | tail -n +2 >output
```

in shell script

```
echo `head -n -1 ankit.txt | tail -n +2` >output
```

Iutput:

```
12ASDF23 FGHJ HJKL 123ASD23 FGHJ HJKL 123ASD23 FGHJ HJKL 123ASD23 FGHJ HJKL
```

Output coming as a single line ... (**That I dont want**)

I tried simply given cat command in shell script but displayed dadata is also as single line

I tried same command without echo in shell script.

even I kept 1 command to show output through shell script :

```
cat ankit.txt
```

output is a single line. wc -l is giving correct count but a simple cp is also giving a single line output.

```
cp ankit.txt output
```

Comment: you don't need to `echo`.

Comment: @Ankit: as Karoly Horvath mentioned, use command in your script without `echo \`\``.

Comment: Did you FTP the file or is it created on the system where you run all of the above ?

Comment: it is working fine without echo and `` .. Thanks !!!

Comment: Then perhaps mark a suitable answer as accepted, so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved? Post and accept one of your own if you don't like the existing answers.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
echo `command`
```

is not only wasteful, it will also perform whitespace splitting and glob expansion on the output from `command` before passing it to `echo`. Usually you simply want

```
command
```

or if you insist on doing a process substitution, and expect its output to be preserved, put it in double quotes:

```
echo "$(command)"
```

(Notice also the switch to the modern, recommended syntax for process substitution.)

But really, why would you want that? If you really do, would it not be better still to have

```
echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(echo "$(echo ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got Windows line endings. You've got two options. Either pre-process your input file to give it UNIX endings:

```
dos2unix ankit.txt
```

or else do that as part of your pipe:

```
dos2unix < ankit.txt | head -n -1 | tail -n +2 > output
```

Note that `dos2unix` has two modes. In the first case, it'll take the input file and rewrite it with UNIX line endings (which is ideal for pre-processing). In the second, it'll read from stdin and write the new output to stdout (which is ideal for pipes).

Comment: If CRLF line endings (`\r\n`) were the problem, the symptom would be different. Try `echo $(printf 'line 1\r\nline 2\r\n')`, for instance.